# Django unit test remove Files created inside the tests

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF view tests. Inside my tests I create files which I want to remove after the tests were running. I'm using `addCleanup` inside my `setUp` method to remove the directories. It basically works, but when I run my complete set of unit tests one dir won't be deleted (I think it's the first one created).

Here is the relevant code:

```
class BaseViewTest(APITestCase):
    client = APIClient()
    base_media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

    def setUp(self):
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=self.base_media_root)

        # add test data
  
        self.addCleanup(shutil.rmtree, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own testrunner

```
class MyTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        super(MyTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(**kwargs)

    def teardown_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        shutil.rmtree(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        super(MyTestRunner, self).teardown_test_environment(**kwargs)
```

and in settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.MyTestRunner'
```